# How i can show this collasible panel close by default?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, dom-events

I'm trying to follow the example here

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/collapsepanels

How is possible show by default the panel closed?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes i have tried to modify the javascript but i don't understand how ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your panel like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default ">
                <div class="panel-heading ">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel 1</h3>
                    <span class="pull-right clickable panel-collapsed"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body collapse" style="display: none;">
                    Founded in 1892 and headquartered in Fairfield, CT, LexisNexis Corporate Affiliations 
                    is a technology and financial services company. 
                    The company offers products and services ranging from aircraft engines, power generation, 
                    water processing, and household appliances, among others. 
                    It operates in business segments including Energy Infrastructure, Aviation, Healthcare, 
                    Transportation, Home &amp; Business Solutions, and GE Capital. 
                    The company also provides medical imaging, business and consumer financing, 
                    and industrial products. 
                    It has presence in North America, Europe, Asia, South America, and Africa. 
                    According to the company's current 10K government filing it had FYE 12/31/2011 revenue of 
                    $147.3 billion and has 301,000 employees.
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ok i understand this but i can'T modify in any way for close the panel by default?

Comment: Sorry misread the code in the sample. look at the uptated post

Answer (score -1):

You do this using jQuery. Use an onclick handler to slideUp or slideDown the panel body.

Here is my fiddle [clickable panel][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/q8L292sk/
```

Comment: @junkfood have a look at this fiddle